# Why does slotting work in this component without specifying the slot name?

Tags: javascript, html, stenciljs, slot, slots

I have two Web Components made with Stencil.js. A `Dropdown` and a `Card`.
Inside my `Dropdown`, I have this:

```
 <div class='dropdown'>
      <slot name="button" />
      <slot />
</div>
```

I nest the two child elements like this:

```
  <ifx-dropdown>
    <ifx-button color="primary">normal button</ifx-button>
    <ifx-dropdown-menu>
      <ifx-dropdown-item>item1</ifx-dropdown-item>
    </ifx-dropdown-menu>
  </ifx-dropdown>
```

As you can see, I am not specifying the slot name for the button. I am not doing `slot='button'`. I am just nesting it, and it works.

But on my second component, the `Card`, it doesn't!

```
<div class="card">
     <div class="card-img">
       <slot name="img" />
     </div>
     <div class="card-body">
     <div class="card-subtitle">{this.subtitle}</div>
     <div class="card-title">{this.headline}</div>
     <p class="card-text">{this.text}</p>
     <slot name="btn" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am nesting it like this:

```
  <ifx-card skyline="true" subtitle="Overline text" headline="Card Title" text="Card Text">
    <img src="myImage" alt="" slot="img">
    <ifx-button color="primary" slot="btn">Button</ifx-button>
  </ifx-card>
```

If I don't specify `slot=img`, the image is not inserted. Same with the below button. So, my question is why? Why does it work without specifying the slot name in the case of the `Dropdown`, but it doesn't in the case of the `Card`?

Comment: **Both!!!** childelements in ``<ifx-dopwdown>`` get _slotted_ (in other words _reflected_ not _moved_!) **to the default slot** ``<slot />``  That is what SLOTs do; they can _reflect_ multiple **lightDOM** elements

Comment: That's not really answering my question at all. I don't care if they're reflected or whatever. My question is why if I insert an element without naming the slot for it, it works with the Dropdown, but it doesn't for the Card? This is what I want to know. I know there's a default slot in the Dropdown, but above it, there's a named one, and yet, when I insert an element or component without naming that slot, it still works, but it doesn't for the Card. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It works in the dropdown because it contains a default slot (`<slot />` without a name attribute). [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots#adding_flexibility_with_slots):

> An unnamed  will be filled with all of the custom element's top-level child nodes that do not have the slot attribute. This includes text nodes.

So if you add `<slot />` to the card component the components without `[slot]` will slotted.

Comment: But in the Dropdown, I have two `slots`. One is default, but the first one is named, and yet, I don't have to name it when I insert the element, where as for the Card, if I don't name it, it's not inserted. Why is that?

Comment: Listen to what Thomas and I both write; Your button is reflected in the default unnamed slot. So that unnamed slot shows TWO elements